# Selecting data from both current and previous records

Tags: mysql, sql

I'd like my query to return a list of "churned" accounts, meaning existing `account_ids` in the below table with the latest record of `plan_id = 4`. This represents a once paying account no longer paying, or "churning."

With that, I need to include the previous value for the account's `plan_id` and calculate the monthly revenue lost from the account's previous `price`.

Here's an example of what the schema looks like when I join the two tables I'm using. (You'll notice accounts with `plan_id = 4` have `NULL` metadata because they don't have revenue.):

```
| account_id | plan_id | start_date           | plan_interval | price  | id     |
|------------|---------|----------------------|---------------|--------|--------|
| 2          | 1       | 2018-01-03T14:52:13Z | month         | 39     | 1      |
| 1          | 3       | 2018-02-07T11:10:17Z | year          | 999    | 3      |
| 1          | 2       | 2018-02-07T11:11:17Z | month         | 99     | 2      |
| 2          | 4       | 2018-03-25T07:09:00Z | (null)        | (null) | (null) |
```

I would like the output to be this, grouped on the `month` and `previous_plan_id`:

```
| month | previous_plan_id | num_churned | monthly_revenue_churned (mrr) |
|-------|------------------|-------------|-------------------------------|
| 3     | 3                | 1           | 83.25                         |
```

So far, I've compiled this query. I still need to pull the previous `plan_id` when an `account_id` moves to `plan_id = 4`, and the previous `price` for that churned account (calculated as monthly revenue or "mrr").

```
SELECT
MONTH(s.start) AS month,
s.plan_id,
COUNT(*) AS num_churned,
SUM(CASE WHEN p.plan_interval = 'month'
     THEN p.price * 0.01 
     ELSE (p.price * 0.01)/12 END) AS mrr
FROM subscriptions s
  LEFT JOIN plans p
  ON p.id = s.plan_id
WHERE s.start = (SELECT MAX(s2.start)
                  FROM subscriptions s2
                  WHERE s.plan_id = 4) 
      AND s.school_id > 1 IN (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT s.school_id)
                          FROM subscriptions)
GROUP BY month, s.plan_id;
```

I think perhaps a `LAG` clause would work but my question is: what can I add to this query to achieve the desired output?

Here's an example: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/449682/3)

Comment: Please explain your definition of "churn".  It is not obvious.

Comment: Edited the question for clarity. A "churned" account is one that previously had a `plan_id` of 1, 2, or 3, but now have a `plan_id = 4`. Theoretically, an account with only one record of `plan_id = 4` is not lost revenue because the account was never on a paying plan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what your calculations are really supposed to be -- the data in your fiddle does not match the data in the question.  But you can do something like this:

```
select s.*, p.price / 12
from (select s.*,
             lag(plan_id) over (partition by account_id order by start_date) as prev_plan_id,
             lag(start_date) over (partition by account_id order by start_date) as prev_start_date
      from subscriptions s 
     ) s join
     plans p
     on s.prev_plan_id = p.id
where plan_id = 4 and prev_plan_id <> 4;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ab0d9c847fd0aa1bdf2dc62d2cc9b440) is a db<>fiddle, which supports more recent versions of MySQL.